# Get key and value types of scala map

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-3

If I have a complicated map type, like

```
type MyMap = Map[(String, String), List[Map[String, Int]]]
```

is there a way to do something like `Map.Key` to get the type of the key (here, `(String, String)`)?

I expect the standard answer is to either declare classes that are the key and value types, or use

```
type MyMapKey = (String, String)
type MyMapValue = List[Map[String, Int]]
type MyMap = Map[MyMapKey, MyMapValue]
```

In this case, I'm using `MyMap` in many places, but only using the key and value types in one place that prepares data for use with the map.  So the key and value types feel like implementation details that don't need names at the same level as MyMap.

It is a common feature in other languages with an expressive type system, so I was expecting to find it in Scala, but it does not seem to be there.

I am using Scala 3 if that matters.

Comment: No there is no out of the box way to do this in **Scala** AFAIK. However, there are a couple of ways you could do what you want. One would be to create your own `KeyOf` typeclass, you other one would be to refine your type alias with a type member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala 3 you can use match types

```
type Key[M] = M match
  case Map[k, _] => k
```

or

```
type Key[M <: Map[?, ?]] = M match
  case Map[k, _] => k
```

Testing:

```
implicitly[Key[MyMap] =:= (String, String)]
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html